# Google Places API Email/Website

Tags: google-places-api

Is there a way to get Email/Website of a particular place using Google Places API? If this is not possible is there a way other than using Google API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Places API provides Details requests and responses using your API key.

The  tag allows for the google places url for that places

e.g.
http://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=10704550479004381649

If you wish to harvest website, fax and opening hours information, it can only be done here.

There is no direct api in the Google Places API that will provide that info.

Just as addressComponents are part of the Details response, i assume tags will be added to the Place Details responses from the API to address this problem.

Comment: The website can definitely be pulled directly via an API - [Place Details API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details).

Answer (score 6):

To retrieve a places website address using Google Places API, you could perform a Places Autocomplete Request with the `input` parameter value set to the name of the place: e.g.`input=Amoeba`

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Amoeba&sensor=false&key=your_api_key

Then using the `reference` from the response you could perform a Places Details Request: e.g.
`reference=ClRMAAAAVzPUTLym999EXs4mKkpTqEmzX0a2kfXCUs4enTvWMHDd06VLvlzsGOdfrRd2QvkiRWs4sNkraAAJlMdytt4O4kYGoJZn4ENL5Ig5QYyeJmMSECDOGMO1MnDFtqzdqD8oDk0aFJr8_s-Y946QOz24YubPUsmoC2vl`

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?reference=ClRMAAAAVzPUTLym999EXs4mKkpTqEmzX0a2kfXCUs4enTvWMHDd06VLvlzsGOdfrRd2QvkiRWs4sNkraAAJlMdytt4O4kYGoJZn4ENL5Ig5QYyeJmMSECDOGMO1MnDFtqzdqD8oDk0aFJr8_s-Y946QOz24YubPUsmoC2vl&sensor=false&key=you_api_key

This would return the details for Amoeba including if available, the parameter `website` which would contain the places website address.

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to use Google Places API, and I have successful queries, fetching Places details, which has all the address information for the place I want to find, but ironically, there is NO WEBSITE attribute in the returned JSON!

The first version of Local search was MUCH better, and always accurate for searches when you know the business name.